# Is there a martial arts manuscript/record or technique using a glaive while on horseback?

Tags: kung-fu, history, weapons, historic-european, shaolin

As the title states, I want to know if there is a martial arts technique with a manuscript record (preferably in English with an image or a video explanation) that uses a glaive type sword while on horseback, such as Guan Dao, Sovnya etc.

Here is an image of the Ming Dynasty Cavalry.

from : https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Guandao_horsemen.jpg

[image: Guandao Horseman]

From : https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ming_lamellar_coat_cavalry.jpg

[image: Ming lamellar Coat Cavalry]

and for sovnya:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sovnya

[image: Sovnya]

[image: Sovnya]

[image: Sovnya]

[image: Sovnya]

I know there is a heavy Guan Dao which was just used for testing troop strength in military exams, or just like European glaives /other cultures that have designs meant to be used by infantry as an anti-cavalry weapon like Pu Dao. I know that some Wudang or Shaolin techniques use this weapon, but so far I have only found recorded uses on foot.

I want to know the technique used by cavalry for this type of weapon, because I haven't found any uses/applications or technique explanations for cavalry use other than paintings of Chinese cavalry and Russian Muscovite cavalry using this kind of weapon on horse.

Here's another image of someone that used Guan Dao on horse; it only shows the exercise for the horse to get used to it.

[Bình-Định SA-LONG-CƯƠNG - EQUESTRIAN ART - Military Horse Riding](http://www.binhdinh-salongcuong.org/GB_EQUESTRIAN%20ART_Military%20Horse%20Riding_Exercices.html)

[image]

[image]

I am curious to know how the Guan Dao was used in battle; I tried googling some names in there which seems like a technique name, but I didn't have any luck other than glaive use on foot techniques.

I saw some videos like this ones, but I am not convinced with them since it looked like it was for show, and it didn't explain much, other than normal swings or slashes on bamboo.

[Korea Horseback moon sword 5bamboo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aV1h6qkVeUE)

[마상무예공연Horseback martial arts show "여명" 제2회 새만금전국지구력승마대회 행사 - MK미디어[무칸]](https://youtu.be/q6d-DTNTRlA?t=99)

Comment: While I haven't found one yet, are you willing to read Western mounted glaive techniques? More of those manuals are available online.

Comment: @SeanDuggan its fine by me hence i include sovnya from russia. iam surprise it exist, since the HEMA community i ask long ago, say they dont have record/manual of such thing nor i found one via google.

Comment: @LiJun This hits an issue with HEMA manuscripts- they are mostly "review manuals" for people who got trained at that school/with that master. There are some HEMA manuals that talk about mounted combat, but I would have to look if they specifically talk about more than simply using spears...

Answer (score 1):

Answered this in my answer to [Is there a legitimate fighting technique using dual sword on horse?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9587/is-there-a-legitimate-fighting-technique-using-dual-sword-on-horse/13297#13297)
Yes.  It's the Korean manual Muyedobotongji/무예도보통지/武藝圖譜通志 (wikipedia article link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muyedobotongji )
[image]